# How do I skip footer for specific email addresses in Google Apps for Work?

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-for-work

In my Google Apps for Work I have a site-wide footer for outgoing email with the footer our lawyers told us to put in email. When you send an email to info@ we forward it to a special address that Freshdesk gave us so it turns into a Freshdesk ticket, the problem is that the footer gets attached and it looks like the footer came from the user when we reply to them or they look at the ticket. It looks horrible, unprofessional and takes space in the screen.

Is there any way to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The help article in the Google Apps Administrator Help Center about how to set a footer is [Append footer setting](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2364576?hl=en)

The step 3 in the referred help article says:

> In the Organizations section, highlight your domain or the
>   organizational unit for which you want to configure settings (see
>   [Configure advanced settings for Gmail](https://support.google.com/a/answer/2786758) for more details).

I think that you should consider to set at least two organizations, one for the employees and one for the info@, then set the footer for the employees organization but not for the info@ organization.

Comment: Aren't different organizations inherently in different domains?

Comment: @J.PabloFernández:  In the context of this question you don't need to have several domains to create a organizational structure to set different footer settings for each one organizational unit.

Comment: Ha! I didn't know that. Thanks. This worked.

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like all email should not get the footer.  Just outgoing emails that are NOT going to an info@ address.  This should be a filter put on the software that is attaching the footer.  Whatever software is attaching the footer should also look to see if it is coming from info@ and if it IS coming from info@ then do not put the footer on.  I would give you a more comprehensive answer however the information you have given is limited.  In summary, you should ask your IT staff "Is is possible to filter the outgoing email to look for info@ in the address and NOT attach the footer to those emails".

Comment: The software adding the footer is Google Apps for Work.